# richfaces datatable selectionchanged listener

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have an extended dataTable in my application, and I would like to load information into my form, when a row is selected. So far this is what I have:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable value="#{myBean.list}" var="item" selection="#{myBean.selection}" selectionMode="single">
    <a4j:ajax execute="@form" render="@from" event="selectionchange" listener="#{myBean.selectionListener}"/>
    <h:column>
        ...
    </h:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

The problem is that the form seems to be rendered before the selectionListener is called, so the data isn't loaded. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: You've got `render="@from"` instead of `"@form"`, but why are you rerendering the whole form anyway? Does the table change?

Answer (score 0):

Makhiel got it right, I misspelled "form". I feel silly now.